# Где правильно использовать async/await в WebAPI

Tags: c#, архитектура, asp.net-web-api, async-await

Мы никогда не использовали async/await (или что-то подобное) в нашем небольшом проекте. Но сейчас проект растет, и мы решили добавить асинхронность.

Проект имеет следующую архитектуру:

- Domain (репозиторий, EF)
- UnitTests
- Service (новый, тут планируется перенести бизнес логику с контроллеров)
- WebUI

Мой вопрос, в каком слое мы должны реализовать асинхронность? Или мы должны сделать это на нескольких слоях? Пожалуйста, подскажите мне, где реализация будет наиболее подходящей?

Например у меня есть метод в контроллере

```
public virtual HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    var entity = Repository.GetAll();

    if (entity != null && entity.Any())
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, entity);
    }

    var message = $"{GenericTypeName}: No content";
    return ErrorMsg(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, message);
}
```

Как мне сделать его асинхронным?

Comment: У вас одна операция Repository.GetAll(); у вас по сути нечего делать ассинхронным.

Comment: @cpp_user ой ли? А если 1000 пользователей одновременно набежит?

Comment: @andreycha: Количество пользователей это уже проблема уровня веб сервера и ассинхронность здесь слабый помощник - более удачные решения это вэбкеши или распределенные запросы в облака.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Repository
{
    public Task<entity> GetAllAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Run<entity>(() =>
        {
            // тут что-то ресурсоёмкое вычисляем

            return entity; // возвращаем результат
        });
    }
}
```

Второй пример, то же самое только с async await

```
class Repository
{
    public async Task<entity> GetAllAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // вернёт управление в вызывающий код
        await Task.Yield();
        // тут что-то ресурсоёмкое вычисляем

        return entity; // возвращаем результат
    }
}
```

Третий пример, если нужно перед возвратом данных вычислить, что-то параллельно

```
class Repository
{
    public async Task<entity> GetAllAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        tasks.Add(Task.Run<entity>(() =>
        {
            // тут что-то ресурсоёмкое вычисляем

            return entity; // возвращаем результат
        }));
        tasks.Add(Task.Run<entity>(() =>
        {
            // тут что-то ресурсоёмкое вычисляем

            return entity; // возвращаем результат
        }));
        tasks.Add(Task.Run<entity>(() =>
        {
            // тут что-то ресурсоёмкое вычисляем

            return entity; // возвращаем результат
        }));
        // дожидаемся окончания всех задач
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        // дальше пробегаемся по списку задач, получаем результат работы каждой и что-то с ним делаем. И возвращаем уже вычисленный нами результат.
    }
}
```

Конечно в реальном боевом приложении код будет немного другой и зависеть от конкретной задачи но принцип будет один и тот же.

Обращаю внимание, что `async/await` это синтаксическая обёртка над `Task.Run` с некоторыми отличиями. А отличия в обработке исключений в процессе выполнения задачи.

Но прежде чем писать асинхронный код обязательно прочитайте про `async/await` И task иначе будет множество ошибок. Особенно внимательно нужно смотреть обработку исключений.

Comment: Осторожнее - конструкция `await Task.Yield();` хоть и возвращает управление в вызывающий код - но все еще сохраняет контекст запроса! Иногда это полезно, но это совсем не то же самое, что выполнение задачи в фоновом потоке.

Answer (score 6):

Асинхронность распространяется на все слои. От нижнего к верхнему. В вашем случае, если Domain асинхронный то и WebUI будет асинхронным.
Не забывайте, что асинхронность нужна только для операций с периферийными устройствами (диск, сеть...) для того, что бы при ожидании ответа не простаивал рабочий поток.

```
class Repository
{
    public Task<entity> GetAllAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using (var db = new DataContext())
        {
            return db.EntitySet.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}

public virtual async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var entity = await Repository.GetAllAsync(cancellationToken);

    if (!entity.Any())
    {
        var message = $"{GenericTypeName}: No content";
        return Content(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, message);
    }

    return Ok(entity);
}
```

Обратите внимание http status code 204 - No content (это не ошибочный статус код)

Для справки: [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Список_кодов_состояния_HTTP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP)

И вообще вам прежде нужно почитать про Task и async await. Task.Run используется для cpu bound operations (Вычислительных операций процессора) async await для ожидания результата этих операций в вызывающем коде или ожидания операций I/O bound operations.

То что касается entity framework то в 6 версии есть асинхронные методы их названия заканчиваются на Async, например .ToListAsync().

Comment: _"асинхронность нужна только для операций с периферийными устройствами"_ -- и при обработке большого количества данных.

Comment: И при массивных вычислениях. В общем асинхронность имеет смысл добавлять везде, где возможен ощутимый "простой" в ожидании результатов вызова метода. 
Но будьте осторожны с асинхронностью. Ибо во первых она делает поведение программы более нелинейным. Это может привести к весьма специфическим багам. А во вторых не всякий метод который можно сделать асинхронным нужно делать асинхронным. Зачастую от асинхронности нет никакого выигрыша.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. А как мне реализовать `GetAllAsync()`? через Task.Run?

Comment: @Evgeniy  А как мне реализовать GetAllAsync()? через Task.Run?

Comment: @MegaTron Если у вас ниже лежащий стек не асинхронный, то городить что-то с Task.Run не нужно, но если очень хочется то ниже добавил ответ.